# Linear Transformation and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

Hi everyone! I need help. I know the rules for subspace.

1. W is nonempty
2. closure under multiplication and addition.

But I don/'t know how to show it for this question.

Comment: Hints: (1) For addition, choose arbitrary elements in your set and consider their sum, remembering to take into account the linearity of $T$ and the closure of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (2) Similarly, chose an arbitrary element in the set, and consider scaling it, accounting for the same factors as in (1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

1) Show that $0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ belongs to $T^{-1}(W)$ by showing that $T(0)=0\in W$.

2) Let $x, y\in T^{-1}(W)$ so that $T(x), T(y)\in W$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. Then we want to show that $ax+by\in T^{-1}(W)$, i.e., $T(ax+by)\in W$ (by the definition of $T^{-1}(W)$).

But $T(ax+by)=aT(x)+bT(y)$ (Why ?) and $aT(x)+bT(y)\in W$ (Why ?). So we are done.